# How to "Start Over" with VisualSvn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I just started with VisualSVN and got things messed up.  I get complaints about working copies being too old (1.6).  I have 1.7 TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN 2.5.5 and have tried many things but nothing helps.

So, I just want to start over, but the option "Add Solution to Subversion" is disabled in Visual Studio 2010.  I tried deleting the repository in VisualSVN Server Manager, and uninstalled/re-installed VisualSVN. But the option remains disabled.

What can I do to just start over?

Answer (score 0):

There was a major change in the way metadata is organized between 1.6 and 1.7, on the client side only.  So 1.6 and 1.7 can talk to the same repositories, but the can not use the same working copies.

By the sounds of it, your problem with the error message would be sorted out by pulling the working copies again using your 1.7 tools.  However, I'm not sure the interop with VS will, so you could also go back to a 1.6 client install.   You'll certainly want to make sure that all clients on your system are 1.6 or 1.7, not a mix.

Comment: I have Tortoise Client 1.7 and VisualSvn 2.5.5.

Comment: Are you saying I have to find a 1.6 client and install it?

Comment: I've never had a 1.6 client on the machine, so I thing the error message is bogus--something else is messed up.  That' why I just want to start over, but how to do that?

Comment: @Dave:  where did the working copies come from? Is everything from your local repo?

Comment: @Dave: also, what is the full version number of your Tortoise client?

Comment: Version 1.7

2011/12/22 20:20:40 (r22413)

Comment: I added the files initially using VisualSvn Server.

Comment: I deleted the .svn folder/file in my working directory, and now the "Add Solution to Subversion" became enable in Visual Studio 10.

Comment: But, I get an error and the complaint about client being 1.6 when I add the solution.

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.7.7, Build 22907 - 64 Bit , 2012/05/15 12:16:05
Subversion 1.7.5, 
apr 1.4.6
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
zlib 1.2.7

Comment: Removing the .svn folder just makes it not a working copy, so you are trying a new import.  What happens if you try to update the WC outside of VS, just using tortoise SVN?

Comment: I can add them all using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: So, everything is working now.  But I was hoping "Add Solution to Subversion" would add all the files required to build the solution, not just the source files.  Not sure if it even does that, but that would have been handy, since I have to manually configure many properties to get the solution to build.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange you have an issue with that. You can simply upgrade your working copy either through **Visual Studio | VisualSVN | Upgrade Working Copy** (if you use *VisualSVN*) or through *TortoiseSVN*.

Please note that the question is completely irrelevant to the server side and is only about upgrading working copy format.

BTW you can always checkout a fresh working copy.

Comment: I don't know what I should do to try it again, since "Add Solution to Subversion" is disabled in Visual Studio.

Comment: Not sure what you think I missed in your reply-- I'd done the Upgrade Working copy previously.  It didn't help.  Add Solution to Subversion was disabled.

Comment: As I said, I can add files, update, and commit OK.  I was just hoping that Add Solution to Subversion would capture the entire Solution including everything needed to reproduce a build --properties, etc.  Maybe it doesn't even do that, but it's disabled once files have been added to SVN outside Visual Studio (using TortoiseSVN or the VisualSvn server.

Comment: I started a brand new VS2010 Solution after uninstalling VisualSVN and everything is working now.   (Intellisense stuff still isn't working in the original project).